# IE6 forces two clicks to trigger Javascript event

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-6, click

I have a web form that has 2 radio buttons, depending on which one is clicked it displays a hidden  element

This works fine in all browsers except for IE6, which, after I click on the radio button, I have to click again (anywhere on the window) and then the element is displayed...has anyone had behavior like this before?

I tried to not use jQuery and do straight getElementById() but I get the same behavior...

Javascript

```
function showHidden(divid) {
  $('#'+divid).css( {'display':'inline'} );
}
```

HTML

```
<input type=radio name=borp  value=1 onChange='showHidden("brandchecks")' > Brand
<input type=radio name=borp  value=2 onChange='showHidden("productchecks")' > Product

<div id='brandchecks' style='display:none;'>
Blah
</div>

<div id='productchecks' style='display:none;'>
Blah
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try calling `.show()`?

Comment: [Stop Living in the Past](http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/)    (IE6 needs to die)   :o)

Comment: tell me about it man. if i wasnt working with so many enterprise customers who's IT departments wont let them upgrade past windows 2000 or download firefox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I remember something about IE firing the onChange [event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) *after* the focus was lost. This behavior would match what you have seen (ie clicking somewhere else to active your code)

Try to change the `onChange` in `onClick` for better results.

**Note**: To be able to click on the text accompanying the radio buttons you could use the [`<label>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) tag, this results in a more user-friendly page.

Comment: great! onClick fixed it. thanks. and also I was always wondering how to make the whole element clickable, didnt even know LABEL existed. really good to know.